# how to get the max() in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get the value from table by the recent created_at. So I used max(created_at). But I get the wrong value.

eg:

### Order.No => created_at

102 => 2016-03-12

103 => 2016-03-16

My result should be ***Order.No 103***, since it has maximum created date. but am getting Order.No 102 as my result. My code is given below:

```
$result = Order::select(DB::raw('id,order_number,end_date,start_date,max(created_at)'),DB::raw('(datediff(end_date,start_date)+1) as Days'))->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
$result->where('main_order', 1);
$result->where('deleted_at','=', NULL);
$result->where('customer_id', Input::get('id'));
$results = $result->get()->toArray();
```

My result is:

```
max(created_at):"2016-03-16"
order_number:"102"    
Days:29
end_date:"2016-03-30"
id:"813115592a364d45b60aa73e7cace5d3"
start_date:"2016-03-02"
```

**I'm getting correct max(created_at) but wrong order_number.** What mistake I made in my code....? Can anyone help me with it???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Has Order No. 103 been soft-deleted by any chance? If it's "deleted_at" is set, you won't get it in the list of results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `orderBy`, like this:

```
$latestDate = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

And then use this variable in your query.

Comment: when i use first() method I can get the result;buy it gives only the fields from db;it does not gives my select(DB:raw('')) fields where i calculated my days.... Means I don't get my calculation.....any help???

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    $result = Order::select(DB::raw('id,order_number,end_date,start_date,max(created_at)'),DB::raw('(datediff(end_date,start_date)+1) as Days'));
$result = $result->where('main_order', 1);
$result = $result->where('deleted_at','=', NULL);
$result = $result->where('customer_id', Input::get('id'));
$results = $result->max('created_at')->get()->toArray();
```

if you use `max()` method you don't need order_by() method anymore

Comment: I am getting error.."Call to a member function toArray() on string"

Comment: @cathy123 check update again, you have to assign to ``$result`` variable